# Django how to render dictionary in the template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this dictionary

```
data={
    'user': user.username,
    'punti_capitano': {'nome_capitano':team.capitano.display_name,'lista_punti':point_cap_list},
    'punti_rider2': {'nome_rider2':team.rider_2.display_name,'lista_punti':point_rider2_list},
    'punti_rider3': {'nome_rider3':team.rider_3.display_name,'lista_punti':point_rider3_list},
    'punti_rider4': {'nome_rider4':team.rider_4.display_name,'lista_punti':point_rider4_list},
    'punti_rider5': {'nome_rider5':team.rider_5.display_name,'lista_punti':point_rider5_list},
    'punti_rider6': {'nome_rider6':team.rider_6.display_name,'lista_punti':point_rider6_list},
    'punti_rider7': {'nome_rider7':team.rider_7.display_name,'lista_punti':point_rider7_list},
    'punti_rider8': {'nome_rider8':team.rider_8.display_name,'lista_punti':point_rider8_list},
    'punti_rider9': {'nome_rider9':team.rider_9.display_name,'lista_punti':point_rider9_list},
}
```

Now I want to create a `HTML` table with all these elements. How do I do that?

i tried this way :

```
<h3>Capitano :{{data.punti_capitano.nome_capitano}} Totale:{{data.punti_capitano.lista_punti.TOT}}</h3>
{% for key,value in data.punti_capitano.lista_punti.items %}
    {% if key != 'TOT' %}
        {{key}} : {{value}}
    {% endif %}
{%endfor%}
<h3>rider_2 :{{data.punti_rider2.nome_rider2}} Totale:{{data.punti_rider2.lista_punti.TOT}}</h3>
{% for key,value in data.punti_rider2.lista_punti.items %}
    {% if key != 'TOT' %}
        {{key}} : {{value}}
    {% endif %}
{%endfor%}
<h3>rider_3 :{{data.punti_rider3.nome_rider3}} Totale:{{data.punti_rider3.lista_punti.TOT}}</h3>
{% for key,value in data.punti_rider3.lista_punti.items %}
    {% if key != 'TOT' %}
        {{key}} : {{value}}
    {% endif %}
{%endfor%}

etc etc
```

but i want something more automatic

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Once you call your context dictionary within your template you just have to loop on that dictionary using django template language.

For example:

```
<table>
{% for element in data %}
 <tr>
    <td>element.user</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Note that the variable `element` will hold the keys but not the values of the dict; you could use `for k, v in data.items` instead (asuming `Python 3.x`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that if you can then you should structure your data in a different way; otherwise there have to be a lot of if/else. This should be done in your view.

Maybe a structure like this, where all similar items are grouped in a list:

```
data = {
    'user': user.username,
    'punti_capitano': {'nome': team.capitano.display_name, 'lista_punti': point_cap_list},
    'punti_rider_list': [
        {'id': 2, 'nome': team.rider_2.display_name, 'lista_punti': point_rider2_list},
        {'id': 3, 'nome': team.rider_3.display_name, 'lista_punti': point_rider3_list},
        {'id': 4, 'nome': team.rider_4.display_name, 'lista_punti': point_rider4_list},
        {'id': 5, 'nome': team.rider_5.display_name, 'lista_punti': point_rider5_list},
        {'id': 6, 'nome': team.rider_6.display_name, 'lista_punti': point_rider6_list},
        {'id': 7, 'nome': team.rider_7.display_name, 'lista_punti': point_rider7_list},
        {'id': 8, 'nome': team.rider_8.display_name, 'lista_punti': point_rider8_list},
        {'id': 9, 'nome': team.rider_9.display_name, 'lista_punti': point_rider9_list},
    ],
}
```

Then in the template you can use something like this to display the common items:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Capitano: {{ data.punti_capitano.nome }}
        </td>
        <td>
            Totale: {{ data.punti_capitano.lista_punti.TOT }}
        </td>
        <td>
        {% for k,v in data.punti_capitano.lista_punti.items %}
            {% if k != 'TOT' %}
            <p>{{ k }}: {{ v }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% for rider in data.punti_rider_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            rider_{{ rider.id }}: {{ rider.nome }}
        </td>
        <td>
            Totale: {{ rider.lista_punti.TOT }}
        </td>
        <td>
        {% for k,v in rider.lista_punti.items %}
            {% if k != 'TOT' %}
            <p>{{ k }}: {{ v }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

You will need to adjust it your specific case, but this should give you a general direction.